# This question shouldn't be closed/looking for reopen voters

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[In D&D 5e, is it at all possible to create half-subclasses?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162026/in-dd-5e-is-it-at-all-possible-to-create-half-subclasses) is closed as Too Broad.  It's not.  It's also not unclear or opinion-based.  It could benefit from better wording, especially in the title, but that's not enough that it should be closed right now.  Can we reopen it?

Answer (score 3):

## I'm not sure

If the question is simply asking **Can I homebrew this**, then yeah, it's answerable and should be reopened.

If it's asking **Can I homebrew this and remain balanced**, that's also possibly answerable by someone who has done it, but it also seems to potentially be a shopping question at that point as it's also potentially **Has someone done this and can show it to me**

If it's asking **How do I do this**, then that isn't answerable because we don't do "Homebrew this for me".

I think OP needs to clarify what they're looking for so we can determine whether or not to reopen. Of course, I may be wrong on my assessment of the above, but that's my gut reaction and why I originally closed.

### Reopened after clarification from OP

OP confirmed [in main chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53071005#53071005) that it is the simple question first listed above. They want to know if it's possible to do it and we can answer that.